# Simple Socks Proxy code? (Arduino + Ethernet module)

Tags: open-source, proxy, hardware, socks

For a new project, i had a strange idea of using an [Arduino](http://arduino.cc) with a [Wiznet W5100](http://www.wiznet.co.kr/Sub_Modules/en/product/Product_Detail.asp?cate1=&cate2=&cate3=&pid=1011) Ethernet module for routing/proxying http data.

The module supports only 4 connections, and i am unsure if this will be enough; 
The available space in arduino (flash/ram) is also of concern.

I can't seem to find any code for an ultra-simple socks4a proxy (c/c++/java/php) so that i can verify the hardware will meet the requirements.

Any linkage or pseudo-code may help.

Update:

Found a simple [c++ implementation](http://www.alhem.net/project/socks4/), and will study this.
I believe if just using CONNECT and not BIND, it should fit the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I found some concise SOCKS (version 5) proxy server code in C++ [here](https://github.com/mfontanini/Programs-Scripts/blob/master/socks5/socks5.cpp).  It's one file.

Also, the [TorCap2 proxifier](https://github.com/cpatulea/TorCap2/) code has SOCKS 4a code you can check out in *DLL/TorCap2Dll.c* which is fairly small and would be re-usable.